# Differing keychain behavior on iOS and MacOS when storing an NSData object in kSecAttrAcct

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, keychain

iOS and MacOS behavior seems to differ when storing and fetching a keychain entry with an `NSData` object in the `kSecAttrAcct` attribute.  Although the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccount) specify that this should be a string, I've seen instances where libraries have stored `NSData` objects instead.

Why is there **different treatment** between iOS and MacOS and **which block of code** (since it's open source) is causing it?

**Fetching the keychain entry on iOS, where the `kSecAttrAcct` value is returned :**

```
(lldb) po queryResult
<__NSArrayM 0x60c00025a9a0>(
{
    acct = <6261726b 6579>;
    agrp = "K7J25DP2KC.com.squareup.ValetTestAPp";
    cdat = "2017-12-01 22:16:57 +0000";
    mdat = "2017-12-01 22:16:57 +0000";
    musr = <>;
    pdmn = ak;
    persistref = <>;
    sha1 = <cf3cf6e6 5aff34b9 0563232a a9c17bee 86e28cfa>;
    svce = "some_identifier_ios";
    sync = 0;
    tomb = 0;
}
)
```

**Fetching the keychain entry in MacOS, where the `kSecAttrAcct` value is not returned:**

```
<__NSArrayM 0x60000005ce30>(
{
    cdat = "2017-12-01 22:14:38 +0000";
    class = genp;
    labl = "some_identifier_macos";
    mdat = "2017-12-01 22:14:38 +0000";
    svce = "some_identifier_macos";
    "v_Ref" = "<SecKeychainItem 0x102c21040 [0x7fffaf65b570]>";
}
)
```

If an `NSString` is stored, both iOS and MacOS return the account value as expected in the dictionary.

```
{
    acct = "accountKey";
    ...
}
```

**Apple Security Source Code**

I spent some time looking through the [latest apple security open source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-58286.1.32/), [SecItem.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-58286.1.32/OSX/sec/Security/SecItem.c) and [SecItem.cpp](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-58286.1.32/OSX/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecItem.cpp).  There also is a `SecItemShim.h` header, which contains the following comment:

```
SecItemShim defines functions and macros for shimming iOS Security implementation to be used inside OSX.
```

Also present are `SecItemAdd_ios`, `SecItemAdd_osx`, `SecItemCopyMatching_ios`, and `SecItemCopyMatching_osx` functions, which indicate there's a difference in implementation between iOS and OSX.

I'm unable to pinpoint the exact line of code that causes the different handling of the `kSecAttrAccount` value though.  If the different behavior is intended, I would expect to see something along the lines of:

```
#if SECITEM_SHIM_OSX
if(isString(account)) { add value to dictionary } else { ignore value }
#elif
add value to dictionary
#endif
```

Perhaps this is a bug? Even if so, it'd still be nice to know which section of code is causing it.

**APPENDIX: The sample code below was run in both an iOS and MacOS project in Xcode.**

```
NSString *identifier = @"some_identifier_<os_name here>";

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [self setValue];
    [self fetchValue];
}

- (void)setValue;
{
    NSData *accountBlob =  [@"accountKey" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *dataBlob = [@"accountValue" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // kSecAttrAccount entry is expected to be a CFString, but a CFDataRef can also be stored as a value.
    NSMutableDictionary *keychainData = [self _baseQuery];
    keychainData[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount] = accountBlob;
    keychainData[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = dataBlob;

    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainData);
    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainData, NULL);

    NSLog(@"Insert Status: %@", @(status));
}

- (id)fetchValue;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [self _baseQuery];

    query[(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit] = (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes] = @YES;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecReturnData] = @NO;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef] = @NO;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef] = @YES;

    CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;

    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &dataTypeRef);
    NSLog(@"Fetch status: %@", @(status));

    NSArray *queryResult = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)dataTypeRef;

    return queryResult;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)_baseQuery;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    query[(__bridge id)kSecAttrService] = identifier;
    query[(__bridge id)kSecClass] = (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword;

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [Apple reply to a dev forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46429):

> There are two implementations of the SecItem API:
>
> the iOS implementation, which is also used for iCloud Keychain on OS X
>
> the OS X implementation, which is a compatibility shim that bridges over to the traditional keychain
>
> Note Both are available in Darwin.  Search the Security project for SecItemUpdate_ios and SecItemUpdate_osx to see how this works under the covers.
>
> The iOS implementation is based on SQLite.  If you’re familiar with SQLite you’ll know that it is, at its core, untyped, and thus the iOS implementation has to do its own type conversion.  This is why that implementation is somewhat forgiving on the types front.  However…
>
> IMPORTANT  I strongly recommend that you use the types specified in the header.  Other types do work but that’s an accident of the implementation rather than a designed in feature.  Moreover, as there are two implementations, it’s not always the case that these accidents line up.
>
> I realise that this rule is broken by various bits of Apple sample code.

This explains why iOS is more forgiving than OSX, and stores the `kSecAttrAccount` value while OSX discards it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that key chain behavior on both iOS & MacOS use AES *and cryptographic hash function* to store NSData object.

---

Note that : ([from here](http://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/tip/How-iOS-encryption-and-data-protection-work))

> Since the release of the iPhone 3GS, Apple has built encryption into
>   the hardware and firmware of its iPads and iPhones. Every iOS device
>   now has a dedicated Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) 256-bit crypto
>   engine that sits between the flash storage and main system memory. The
>   engine works in conjunction with the SHA-1 cryptographic hash function
>   -- which is implemented in the hardware as well -- to reduce overhead for cryptographic operations.

---

Finally, in my opinion:

**iOS** keychain behavior on *iOS when storing an NSData* object in kSecAttrAcct *will have to take in consideration the encryption into the hardware and firmware*, but the **MacOS** keychain behavior will not have to deal with firmware/hardware... It probably explain the difference..